# ¿Como determinar la direccion que se mueve el mouse?

Tags: javascript, eventos, mouse

## ¿Como determinar la dirección que se mueve el mouse?

### Descripción inicial:

Estoy haciendo un juego sencillo, es una versión del juego `Snake` o una serpiente que come manzana y aumenta su cola sin que pueda tocar su cola o las paredes.

### Problema:

Hay veces que mi fórmula se equivoca y no determina la dirección correcta a la que debe moverse y es muy difícil hacer que se mueva en la dirección que indico al mover el mouse.

### Código:

```JavaScript
//Canvas es una variable que contiene un elemento canvas.
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    let dim=snake.dims[0];
    let is_x=(dim.x==e.clientX)?SQUAL:(dim.x>e.clientX)?MAYOR:MENOR;
    let is_y=(dim.y==e.clientY)?SQUAL:(dim.y>e.clientY)?MAYOR:MENOR;
    if (is_x && is_y){//Si no son iguales.
        if (is_x>is_y){//BOTTOM | LEFT
            //Sedemos el control a BOTTOM o a LEFT.
            dim.address=( dim.y-e.clientY<e.clientX-dim.x )?BOTTOM:LEFT;
        }else{//TOP | RIGHT
            //Sedemos el control a TOP o a RIGHT.
            dim.address=( e.clientY-dim.y<dim.x-e.clientX )?TOP:RIGHT;
        }
    }
});
```

### Descripciones de las clases usadas:

#### Clase Dim:

> Es una clase que define las dimensiones(`x,y,width,height`) del los objeto, tambien define su dirección(`address`).
> Tiene dos constructores: El primero determina los atributos anteriormente mencionado, el segundo es una funcion estática que retorna un nuevo objeto Dim:

```JavaScript
Dim.new_dim=function(dim){
   return new Dim(dim.x,dim.y,dim.width,dim.height,dim.address);
};
```

#### Clase Snake:

> snake es un objeto que define como atributo una colección de `Dim` que representan toda la cola, el primer elemento es el que se necesita cambiar la dirección(`snake.dims[0].address`) por medio del evento, la  serpiente cambiará de posición de la siguiente manera:

```JavaScript
snake.dims[1].address=Dim.new_dim(snake.dims[0]);
```

> La variable `address` determinará en que dirección moverse, acepta estos valores: `TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT y RIGHT`. Que con un switch cambiará la posición de la primera cola o `snake.dims[0]`.

### Codigo Completo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Example.</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <style>
            canvas{
                border:3px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas">Su navegador esta muy obsoleto, deberia descargar uno que sea mas actualizado.</canvas>
        <script>
            const MAX_WIDTH=500,
                       MAX_HEIGHT=500,
                        //Para identificar la posicion de los objetos.
                       TOP=0,
                       BOTTOM=1,
                       LEFT=2,
                       RIGHT=3,
                       //Para determinar que direccion se mueve el mouse.
                       SQUAL=0,
                       MAYOR=1,
                       MENOR=0;
            var snake, //La serpiente del juego.
                   time_game=300, //Tiempo de retraso en la serpiente.
                   ctx, //Contexto 2d del elemento canvas.
                   id_interval_game;//Tendra el id del setInteval para la funcion game.
             
            class Dim{
                constructor(x,y,width,height,address){
                    this.x=x;
                    this.y=y;
                    this.width=width;
                    this.height=height;
                    this.address=address;
                }
            }
            Dim.new_dim=function(dim){
                return new Dim(dim.x,dim.y,dim.width,dim.height,dim.address);
            }
            class Snake{
                constructor(dim,color="green"){
                    this.dims=[dim];
                    this.color=color;
                }
                move_dim(dim,speed){
                    switch ( dim.address ){
                        case TOP:// -speed
                            dim.y-=speed;
                            break;
                        case BOTTOM:// +speed
                            dim.y+=speed;
                            break;
                        case RIGHT://+speed
                            dim.x+=speed;
                            break;
                        case LEFT://-speed
                            dim.x-=speed;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                update(speed,ctx){
                    this.deleted_all(ctx);
                    let now=Dim.new_dim(this.dims[0]);
                    this.move_dim(this.dims[0],speed);
                    for (let i=1;i<this.dims.length;i++){
                        let after=Dim.new_dim(this.dims[i]);
                        this.dims[i]=now;//arrastramos la cola actual a donde va la cola anterior.
                        now=after;
                        //Complovamos si la cabeza toca su cola.
                        if (this.dims[0].x==now.x && this.dims[0].y==now.y){
                            return true;//Game-Over.
                        }
                    }
                    return false;//Normal
                }
                draw(ctx){
                    let fillStyle=ctx.fillStyle;//Para guardar el color usado anteriormente.
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle=this.color;
                    for ( let dim of this.dims ){
                        ctx.fillRect(dim.x,dim.y,dim.width,dim.height);
                    }
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fillStyle=fillStyle;
                }
                deleted_all(ctx){
                    for (let dim of this.dims){
                        ctx.clearRect(dim.x,dim.y,dim.width,dim.height);
                    }
                }
            };
            
            window.onload=function(){
                 let canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
                 canvas.setAttribute("width",MAX_WIDTH+"px");
                 canvas.setAttribute("height",MAX_HEIGHT+"px");
                 
                 ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
                 
                 canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
                     /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                     //Aqui va el codigo que causa el problema.
                     let dim=snake.dims[0];
                     let is_x=(dim.x==e.clientX)?SQUAL:(dim.x>e.clientX)?MAYOR:MENOR;
                     let is_y=(dim.y==e.clientY)?SQUAL:(dim.y>e.clientY)?MAYOR:MENOR;
                     if (is_x && is_y){//Si no son iguales.
                         if (is_x>is_y){//BOTTOM | LEFT
                             //Sedemos el control a BOTTOM o a LEFT.
                            dim.address=( dim.y-e.clientY<e.clientX-dim.x )?BOTTOM:LEFT;
                         }else{//TOP | RIGHT
                             //Sedemos el control a TOP o a RIGHT.
                            dim.address=( e.clientY-dim.y<dim.x-e.clientX )?TOP:RIGHT;
                         }
                     }
                 });
                 snake=new Snake(
                                       new Dim(MAX_WIDTH>>1,MAX_HEIGHT>>1,10,10,LEFT),
                                      "red"
                              );
                 id_interval_game=setInterval(game,time_game);//Iniciamos el juego.
            }
            function game(){
                if (snake.update(10,ctx) || snake.dims[0].x>MAX_WIDTH || snake.dims[0].x<0 || snake.dims[0].y>MAX_HEIGHT || snake.dims[0].y<0 ){//Game over.
                    alert("Game-Over. :  ( ");
                    clearInterval(id_interval_game);
                }
                snake.draw(ctx);
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sin ánimos de quitar el mérito a tu trabajo, en mi opinión, y sólo es una opinión, manejar el movimiento del actor mediante el teclado sería un poco más efectivo que hacerlo mediante el mouse. Repito que es sólo una opinión y no una sugerencia. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioCosteras Gracias por la opinión:), También lo hice, pero me gustaría manejar el evento mouse y toucher, con el evento toucher pienso utilizar la misma fórmula, pero no sé si debo cambiarla en el evento toucher( Ojo: Mi pregunta solo tiene que ver para el evento mousemove y cuando obtenga la respuesta la adapto al toucher ).

Comment: yéndonos al lado matemático. Tendrías que evaluar la posición en el eje x o y. Si la serpiente está yendo hacia arriba o hacia abajo solo tiene permitido moverse a los lado, por lo que al mover el maouse tendrás que evaluar la posición X del mouse y la de la serpiente. Si la posición del X del mouse es mayor a la de la serpiente entonces te mueves a la derecha, de lo contrario a la izquierda. Lo mismo para ir hacia arriba o abajo.

Comment: @Christian Eso es lo que trato de hacer con la formula que enseñe: `let is_x=(dim.x==event.clientX)?SQUAL:(dim.x>event.clientX)?MAYOR:MENOR;
    let is_y=(dim.y==event.clientY)?SQUAL:(dim.y>event.clientY)?MAYOR:MENOR;
    if (is_x && is_y){//Si no son iguales.
        if (is_x>is_y){//BOTTOM | LEFT
            //Sedemos el control a BOTTOM o a LEFT.
            dim.address=( dim.y-event.clientY<event.clientX-dim.x )?BOTTOM:LEFT;
        }else{//TOP | RIGHT
            //Sedemos el control a TOP o a RIGHT.
      dim.address=( event.clientY-dim.y<dim.x-event.clientX )?TOP:RIGHT;
}   }`

Comment: podrías poner todo el código para replicar tu problema. Creo que tengo lo solución pero me hace falta probarlo y lo haría pero no sé como funciona un canvas ni nada de eso. No soy experto en JS

Comment: @Christian listo.

Answer (score 0):

Cambié la fórmula para lograr el efecto que quiero:

```JavaScript
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
    let dim=snake.dims[0];
    
    //Creamos un flag que dirá si el mous esta menor o igual a la posición X y Y de la serpiente.
    let is_x=(dim.x==e.clientX)?SQUAL:(e.clientX>dim.x)?MAYOR:MENOR;//Mayor significa RIGHT
    let is_y=(dim.y==e.clientY)?SQUAL:(e.clientY>dim.y)?MAYOR:MENOR;//Mayor significa BOTTOM.
    let dis_x=(is_x==MAYOR)?e.clientX-dim.x:dim.x-e.clientX;
    let dis_y=(is_y==MAYOR)?e.clientY-dim.y:dim.y-e.clientY;
    if (dis_x>dis_y){
        dim.address=(is_x==MAYOR)?RIGHT:LEFT;
    }else{
        dim.address=(is_y==MAYOR)?BOTTOM:TOP;
    }
});
```

### Expricacion:

1- Creamos dos flags, que nos dirá si la posición del mouse es menor, igual o mayor a la posición de la serpiente.

```JavaScript
    //Creamos un flag que dirá si el mous esta menor o igual a la posición X y Y de la serpiente.
    let is_x=(dim.x==e.clientX)?SQUAL:(e.clientX>dim.x)?MAYOR:MENOR;//Mayor significa RIGHT
    let is_y=(dim.y==e.clientY)?SQUAL:(e.clientY>dim.y)?MAYOR:MENOR;//Mayor significa BOTTOM.
```

2- Determinamos la distancia que separa a la serpiente del mouse en relación con la posición `x` e `y`:

```JavaScript
    let dis_x=(is_x==MAYOR)?e.clientX-dim.x:dim.x-e.clientX;
    let dis_y=(is_y==MAYOR)?e.clientY-dim.y:dim.y-e.clientY;
```

3- Decidimos si sedemos  el control a `RIGHT | LEFT` o a `BOTTOM | TOP` lo que decidiremos de esta manera: `if (dis_x>dis_y){` lo cual si es true entonces le cedemos el control a `RIGHT | LEFT`, pero si no es mayor entonces le cedemos el control a `BOTTOM | TOP`.

4.1- Si la distancia `x` es mayor a la distancia `y` entonces  tomamos la variable `is_x` para determinar si el mouse esta a la derecha de la serpiente(`RIGHT`), sino esta a la izquierda de la serpiente(`LEFT`)  y haci cambiamos su dirección:

```JavaScript
    dim.address=(is_x==MAYOR)?RIGHT:LEFT;
```

4.2- Si la distancia `x` es menor o igual a la distancia `y` entonces hacemos el paso anterior(Con la variable `is_y`) para ver si la serpiente toma la dirección `BOTTOM` o `TOP`:

```JavaScript
    dim.address=(is_y==MAYOR)?BOTTOM:TOP;
```